# How to handle Chrome rendering dynamically added elements with incomplete CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am setting class name on `<A>` elements (present in original HTML) under which SVG elements are appended as they are being loaded with $.get. The SVG elements have styles that are not applied on Chrome, unless I do something that forces a re-render. For example, checking/unchecking a box for a style attribute in Developer view, or using Brackets IDE and modifying CSS (which causes Brackets to tear our all CSS and replace it for every character typed).

When I put the class-adding code on setTimeout, with at least 80ms interval, it works. In IE11, Edge, Safari and Firefox, it works without this work-around. According to Network pane, CSS loads before the scripts (also tried placing them at the tail instead of head),  This is a problem of Chrome not properly managing the render sequence (most likely trying to be too smart with minimal re-render algorithm that works against me).

How do I handle this properly?

This is a [working version](http://www.01binary.us/navigation/index.htm), working because I hard-coded the styles normally applied with jQuery (in production I would render this server-side but it's not a satisfying solution).

Here's the [broken version](http://www.01binary.us/navigation-broken/index.htm)

You can verify that moving lines 55-64 in `navigation.js` into a `setTimeout` will make it work.

Using Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit) on Mac OS X

Edit: relevant HTML and JS as requested, see links above for complete picture.

**index.htm**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"></link>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/navigation.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="logo" class="icon" data-src="images/logo.svg"></div>

    <nav data-src="images/navigation.svg">
      <a href="index.htm">news</a>
      <a href="articles.htm">articles</a>
      <a href="projects.htm">projects</a>
      <a href="about.htm">about</a>
    </nav>
```

**navigation.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadNavigationButtons();
});

function loadNavigationButtons() {
  var buttonParts =
      [
        "matte",
        "border",
        "highlight",
        "icon",
        "selection"
      ];

  return $.Deferred(function(callback) {
    $("nav a").each(function(index) {
      var navigationIconSet = $(this)
        .closest("nav[data-src]")
        .attr("data-src");

      var buttonName = $(this).text();
      $(this).text("");

      if (document.URL.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) != -1) {
        // Add navigation-selected class to <a>
        $(this).addClass("navigation-selected");
      } else {
        // Add navigation-unselected class to <a>
        $(this).addClass("navigation-unselected");
      }

      for (var partIndex in buttonParts) {
        loadIcon(
          // Prepend to this element.
          $(this),

          // Attempt to find a part for this specific button.
          navigationIconSet + "#" + buttonName + "-" + buttonParts[partIndex],

          // Fallback to generic part name.
          navigationIconSet + "#" + buttonParts[partIndex],

          // Class to apply.
          "navigation navigation-" + buttonParts[partIndex]

          // Not passing callback parameter
        );
      }

      // Append button text.
      $("<div></div>")
        .text(buttonName)
        .addClass("navigation navigation-text")
        .appendTo($(this));
    });

    callback.resolve();
  });
}

function loadIcon($container, iconUri, fallbackUri, classToApply, callbackParameter) {
  if (~iconUri.indexOf("#")) {
    var sourceComponents = iconUri.split("#");
    var fallbackComponents;

    if (fallbackUri) {
      fallbackComponents = fallbackUri.split("#");

      // Support fallback only within the same icon set.
      if (sourceComponents[0] != fallbackComponents[0]) {
        return $.Deferred(function(callback) {
          callback.reject($container, null, callbackParameter)
        });
      }
    } else {
      fallbackComponents = [null, null];
    }

    return loadIconFromDefinition(
      $container,
      sourceComponents[0],
      sourceComponents[1],
      fallbackComponents[1],
      classToApply,
      callbackParameter);
  } else {
    return loadIconFromFile(
      $container, iconUri, classToApply, callbackParameter);
  }
}

function loadIconFromFile($container, iconUri, classToApply, callbackParameter) {
  return $.Deferred(function(callback) {
    $.get(iconUri).done(function(icon) {
      callback.resolve(
        $("svg", icon).prependTo($container),
        null,
        callbackParameter);
    });
  });
}

function loadIconDefinition(definitionUri) {
  if (!loadIconDefinition.loaded) {
    loadIconDefinition.loaded = {};
  }

  if (loadIconDefinition.loaded[definitionUri]) {
    return loadIconDefinition.loaded[definitionUri];
  }

  loadIconDefinition.loaded[definitionUri] =
    $.Deferred(function(callback) {
      loadIconFromFile($("body"), definitionUri)
        .then(function($loaded) {
      // Hide definition after it's loaded.
      $loaded.get(0).setAttributeNS(null, "style", "display:none");
      callback.resolve($loaded);
    });
  });

  return loadIconDefinition.loaded[definitionUri];
}

function loadIconFromDefinition(
$container, definitionUri, groupName, fallbackGroupName, classToApply, callbackParameter) {
  return $.Deferred(function(callback) {
    loadIconDefinition(definitionUri).then(function($loaded) {
      if (fallbackGroupName &&
          !$loaded.find("#" + groupName).length) {
        groupName = fallbackGroupName;
      }
      callback.resolve(
        $("<svg class=\"" + classToApply + "\"><use xlink:href='#" + groupName + "'></use></svg>")
        .prependTo($container),
        $loaded,
        callbackParameter);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Raise a Chrome bug on their bugtracker.

Comment: I could not post a jsFiddle due to external resources being required for the demo (in this case a small .svg). I was warned that cross-site request would not work.

Comment: Submitted report here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=622960#

Comment: I've found a number of issues with chrome's css renderer that can be worked around by putting it in a setTimeout. I just think their css render has some longstanding weirdo bugs in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like this question spent enough time in the purgatory.

Suggested work-arounds:

- Keep adding children dynamically but always set parent element classes on server-side. In case of ASP.net, use a Razor expression that renders short HTML for parent element(s) in question with class attribute already set before browser gets the page. This is the work-around I selected.
- Hide element(s) in question until setTimeout with high enough delay elapses, which sets all necessary classes and unhides the element(s) to reduce flicker. User experience can be smoothed further by using a loading progress bar in a "dialog" which dims the rest of the page and proceeds to fade it in.

Not accomplished by this solution:

- Find an event or Promise that we can hook into when the browser is in a state that updating class attribute on DOM elements is able to trigger re-render.

Misc:

- Filed Chromium bug to describe this situation... Perhaps in 5 years it will be fixed.